# mediaelement.js in Safari in Windows XP SP3

Tags: windows-7, safari, windows-xp, mediaelement.js

I'm testing mediaelement.js with various OS (Win XP and 7 so far) and browser combinations (Chrome, FF, IE8, Opera) before using it on my own website. Those combinations seem great but after hours of effort I can't get Safari to work well enough under Windows XP SP3 to do a true test of whether mediaelement.js works in Safari under Windows XP (Safari normally doesn't respond when visiting web pages with or without mediaelement).

Forum posters say that one shouldn't bother to try to make Safari and XP work together but my users worldwide use many combinations of OS and browser so I need to know whether to warn them off from trying to use my mediaelement-based pages with Safari and XP.

Can someone please confirm or deny that Safari on a Windows XP PC can play the video on http://mediaelementjs.com ? I would be most grateful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I also tried this running an XP VM with all the latest updates.  It worked with Safari 5.1.5 and I also upgraded it to 5.1.7 and both played the video without a hitch.

Answer (score 0):

I found an old Win XP PC in the attic, installed Safari 5.1.7 and it handled the video on http://mediaelementjs.com fine.

Answer (score 0):

I've been having this issue too. It's only on Safari on Windows.  So far, I've had issues with Safari telling me that certain MediaElement functions don't exist:

```
TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating 'this.pluginApi.loadMedia()')
```

It's obviously an issue with the Flash fallback and it occurs after calling `.load()`.  It seems like a bug in MediaElementJS because that is an internal function.

I started setting the source like this:

```
var player = $('#wp_mep_1')[0].player.media;
player.src = 'video_url.mp4';
```

and then for Safari, or the Flash fallback, I had to manually change the flashvars after clicking to get the video to update:

```
$j('#me_flash_0').attr('flashvars','id=me_flash_0&isvideo=true&autoplay=false&
preload=none&width=480&startvolume=0.8&timerrate=250&flashstreamer=&height=270&
file='+video_urls[slider_position]+'.mp4');
```